# How to delete data by selecting a particular button

Tags: java, android

I am working with android. I want to delete the particular button that i have selected.. I am using onContextItemSelected for selecting the button.What do I write inside

`public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {}` of setPositiveButton??

```
 @Override  
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {  

        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
        String number;
        final Context context = this;

        try
        {
                //number=new ContactListAdapter (this).numberList.get(info.position);



              if(item.getTitle()=="View ")
              {
                Dialog dialog=new Dialog(HubActivity.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.driver_details);

                dialog.setTitle("Driver Details");
                dialog.show();

              }  
              else if(item.getTitle()=="Edit ")
              {
                Dialog dialog=new Dialog(HubActivity.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_driver);
                dialog.setTitle("Edit Details");
                dialog.show();

              }
              else if(item.getTitle()=="Delete ")
              {

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        context);

                    // set title
                    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Delete");

                    // set dialog message
                    alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage("Are you sure to delete ?")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked, close
                                // current activity
                                //MainActivity.this.finish();
                            }   
                          })
                        .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked, just close
                                // the dialog box and do nothing
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                        // create alert dialog
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                        // show it
                        alertDialog.show();
              }
```

Comment: where is the button instance in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have defined the button in your xml layout, you cannot delete it but you can remove it from the view by setting (and this is the most common case):

```
// Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

The above line will go inside your public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {}.

If you have added the button dynamically within the code, you can remove it by getting the parent layout and doing:

```
ViewGroup.removeView(button);
```